# UIPanGestureRecognizer not behaving as expected

Tags: sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, skspritenode, uipangesturerecognizer

The following code is being used to change the colour of sprites as my finger pans over them. It works but the sprites only change colour after the gesture has ended. Eg I start by panning over the sprites and draw a shape - nothing changes as I pan - then I lift my finger and the sprites change colour.

the print statements are reporting the correct sprite names and all the print statements are being triggered... but the sprite colour change isn't... until the end.

Its confusing me so I am hoping someone can explain.

```
   @objc func drawingpan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    recognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    if recognizer.state == .began {

        print("drawingbegan")
        var touchLocation = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)
        var touchLocation2 = self.convertPoint(fromView: touchLocation)
        let nn = nodes(at: touchLocation2)
        if nn.count > 0 {
            if let dotSpriteTapped = nn.first! as? SKSpriteNode {
                print("touchebeganpan",dotSpriteTapped.name)
                for spritesquare in MyVariables.allsprites {
                    if dotSpriteTapped.name == spritesquare.name {
                        print("changecolorpan",dotSpriteTapped.name)
                        spritesquare.color = UIColor.red
                    }
                }}
        }
    }

} else if recognizer.state == .changed {
print("touchechangedx")

var touchLocation = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)
var touchLocation2 = self.convertPoint(fromView: touchLocation)
let nn = nodes(at: touchLocation2)
if nn.count > 0 {
    if let dotSpriteTapped = nn.first! as? SKSpriteNode {
        for spritesquare in MyVariables.allsprites {
            if dotSpriteTapped.name == spritesquare.name {
                print("namesmatch",dotSpriteTapped.name)
                spritesquare.color = UIColor.red
}
}}
}
}


    } else if recognizer.state == .ended {
    //recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    }}
```

Comment: I am not following your logic here.... why are you bothering with matching names at all.  I must assume that the sprites in MyVariables are just copies of sprites with the same name.

Comment: its because ive got several groups of sprites and I am just matching one specific sprite group to be colour changed. I think the number of sprites I was checking was too many for the gesturerecognizer to test an good time so it was causing the lag..

Comment: ive removed the need to name check through all the sprites and the gesturerecognizer is working correctly now.

Comment: that still makes no sense.  `nn` contains all the sprites you are touching.  Just change the color of the sprites in `nn`.  If you are looking for a certain type, use some way to distinguish it. E.G. sprite name could be "Sprite_light" and you just search for "_light".  What you are doing now is going to cause issues because it is possible for  two sprites to have the same name, and you may not be changing the same sprite (which is going to be my assumption here)

Comment: yes you are right, ive changed it so that I am checking if the touched nodes name contains a string.